# Grouped facets with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, faceted-search

I'm looking for a way to display my facets in a grouped list. For example i have some users and a facet to filter by country, this gives me:

- **Country**

  - Holland (5)
  - England (2)
  - Egypt (5)
  - Rwanda (2)

And what i would like to have is:

- **Europe**

  - Holland (5)
  - England (2)
- **Africa**

  - Egypt (5)
  - Rwanda (2)

I'm using the Tire gem in a Rails application, my models and relations are like this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select

I've googled for an example on this for hours, just can't find anything for nested /grouped facets what makes sense to me in Elasticsearch. Hope someone can help me in the right direction! Many thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: There is no way to do that as for now. But in a future (and hopefully soon to be) release of ES, there will be an awesome aggregator module that will be able to do just that. I am waiting for this, too.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible in solr? I'm in the beginning of this project.. might switch to sunsport / solr if this is supported.

Comment: sorry, I do not know anything about Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably handle this by indexing the data in two ways and then just parse the outout. Use the "object" version to apply filters, and get your parsing version as a facet to display filters.

For example:

```
    "mydocument":{
    "attributes":[     
       "location":{
        {"continent":"europe",
        "country":"england"
       },
     "fur_style":"long"
   ],
"facets":[
       {"location":"Europe##england"},
       {"fur_style":"long"
    ]
    }
```

when you get your data back, you'll have:

```
"facets":[
{"location":"Europe##england",
"total":5},
{"location":"africa##egypt",
"total":7}
{"fur_style":"long",
 "total":3}
etc etc
]
```

In your application, you just have to loop through and break apart the terms using the ## delimiter (or whatever you want it to be).

Comment: I was thinking about something like this as well, if there is no other way for now i guess i will take this approach. Thanks!